# Prevent parent view controller from receiving UITouch in child controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, parent-child, uitouch, uiresponder

So, in my app, then a map annotation is pressed, It reveals a modal view controller. Then when an element that modal controller is pressed, I open another, smaller controller. In both controllers, I have implemented the method

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint([self.view viewWithTag:21].frame, touchPoint)) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Here is an image that shows my layout:
[image: Layout Image]

My problem is that when I touch in yellow circle one, the second modal dismisses, and after that, the first modal dismisses. SO, how can I prevent the first modal from receiving the touch.

PS: both modals are transparent UIViews, with smaller views inside them to display the content.

Comment: some sort of check for the red view being present in the `touchesEnd` of the green view. `if (redView == false) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the event is passed through the view controller to the next responder.

In the class reference of UIResponder.

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However
>   immediate UIKit subclasses of UIResponder, particularly UIView,
>   forward the message up the responder chain. To forward the message to
>   the next responder, send the message to super (the superclass
>   implementation); do not send the message directly to the next
>   responder. For example,
>
> [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
>
> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, if only as stub (empty) implementations.

So if you don't want the event to forward to the next responder, you should override the other methods.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint([self.view viewWithTag:21].frame, touchPoint)) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that detailed answer.